# Retrieving future value in Python using offset variable from another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve values from future dates using an offset variable in a separate row in Python.  For instance, I have the dataframe `df` below, and I'd like to find a way to produce Column C:

```
Orig A  Orig B  Desired Column C
54         1           76
76         4           46
14         3           46
35         1           -3
-3         0           -3
46         0           46
64         0           64
93         0           93
72         0           72
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you give context to what you are asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NumPy for a vectorised solution:

```
import numpy as np

idx = np.arange(df.shape[0]) + df['OrigB'].values
df['C'] = df['OrigA'].iloc[idx].values

print(df)

   OrigA  OrigB   C
0     54      1  76
1     76      4  46
2     14      3  46
3     35      1  -3
4     -3      0  -3
5     46      0  46
6     64      0  64
7     93      0  93
8     72      0  72
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {"Orig A": [54,76,14,35,-3,46,64,93,72],
        "Orig B": [1,4,3,1,0,0,0,0,0],
        "Desired Column C": [76,46,46,-3,-3,46,64,93,72]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

df["desired_test"] = [df["Orig A"].values[i+j] for i,j in enumerate(df["Orig B"].values)]

df

   Orig A  Orig B  Desired Column C  desired_test
0      54       1                76            76
1      76       4                46            46
2      14       3                46            46
3      35       1                -3            -3
4      -3       0                -3            -3
5      46       0                46            46
6      64       0                64            64
7      93       0                93            93
8      72       0                72            72
```

Comment: hi @W.Dodge, thanks for your script.  I received the following error when trying to implement it on the broader dataset: IndexError: index 15912 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 15912.